# Formula on Cell changes when I drag it down in excel

Tags: excel

I have a formula which goes like the one below

```
=COUNTIF(D10:D1000,Q13)
```

But everytime I drag it down D10 becomes D11. All I want to change is Q13 to Q14 to Q15 and so on but not the D10. So the above formula is for Q13 and in Q14 I want the formula to be

```
=COUNTIF(D10:D1000,Q14)
```

And for Q15

```
=COUNTIF(D10:D1000,Q15)
```

Notice that D10 doesn't change but Q+value does.

Kindly advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lock the range. This can be done by adding dollar signs before the references (or pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> after typing/selecting the range:

```
=COUNTIF($D$10:$D$1000,Q13)
```

Though in this situation locking the row should be enough, since you're dragging down, the `D` won't change (you can add the dollar signs where required, or press <kbd>F4</kbd> repeatedly until you get the right lock):

```
=COUNTIF(D$10:D$1000,Q13)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `D10` to stay the same specify an absolute reference using `$`, like this:

```
=COUNTIF($D$10:D1000,Q13)
```

Comment: It works sir but I'm now facing another problem. This formula `=COUNTIF($D$10:D1000,Q13)` changes to this one `=COUNTIF($D$10:$D$11,Q13)` whenever the screen loads or if it came across an error. Any advice?